# Showing Images(or Media) on Button Click on Randomly changing Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, random

I want to show 5 xml layouts in random, and also i'l shuffle them on click of appropriate button each appeared xml file. Upto that the below code is working awesomely.----*****I have put a delay of 0.75 seconds on each shuffle of the xml file.In this delay I have a sound to play.I have no really Idea How to achieve this.In the below code I used Switch-Case , But it is not working.My requirement is if I Click  on the Button on xml file1 , I want to play Sound1, if the Button is from Xml file 5 , I want to play the corresponding Sound5 And so on....like that for 0.75 seconds and move to next XML file and the cycle repeats.****----

```
public class ReceivingActivity extends Activity{

    Random random = new Random();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int mPosition = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private List<Integer> mLayouts;
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mLayouts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                mLayouts.add(R.layout.first);
                mLayouts.add(R.layout.second);
                mLayouts.add(R.layout.third);
                mLayouts.add(R.layout.fourth);
                mLayouts.add(R.layout.fifth);

                Collections.shuffle(mLayouts);
                setContentView(mLayouts.get(mPosition));

                mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnid);
                mButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);
                mPosition++;
    }

    private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WTH is happening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(mPosition >= mLayouts.size()){
                        int lastId = mLayouts.get(mLayouts.size() - 1);
                        Collections.shuffle(mLayouts);
                        while (lastId == mLayouts.get(0)) {
                            Collections.shuffle(mLayouts);
                        }
                        mPosition = 0;
                    }
                    setContentView(mLayouts.get(mPosition));


                switch (mLayouts.get(mPosition)) {
                    case R.layout.first:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        break;

                    case R.layout.second:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Some sound                     
                        iv2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                        break;

                    case R.layout.third:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "third", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Some media , Different for each Layout.. 

                        iv3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                        break;  

                    case R.layout.fourth:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fourth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        iv4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                        break;

                    case R.layout.fifth:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fifth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        iv5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                        break;  
                    default:
                        break;
                    }


                    mPosition++;
                    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnid);
                    mButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);
                }

            }, 2050);
        }
    };


                    mPosition++;
                    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnid);
                    mButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);
                }
            }, 750);
        }
    };
}
```

Any kind help is highly helpful.

Comment: Don't switch against `mPosition` if you're going to test it against the layouts ids. If you want to test against the layouts ids use `switch(mLayouts.get(mPosition))` .

Comment: Hi, In the above edited, Switching with "switch(mlayouts.get(mPosition))"is working fine* only for the toast messages,If I put Imageresources as above, Null pointer exception is coming.                                                                                   *--->That Switching is starting from second shuffled layout.First one is going plain & the remaining all works Perfectly showing the toast. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the android:tag to differentiate between the buttons.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:tag="1"/>
```

And then in the code retrieve the tag

```
mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnid);
int id = Integer.parseInt(mButton.getTag());

switch(id) {
    ...
}
```